# How to save a video to file using sampleBuffer, captureOutput in Swift 3?

Tags: swift, macos, video-streaming, video-capture, video-encoding

I'm trying to get my head around this. I want to record live video with Swift on OSX, using the *AVAssetWriterInput*.

I created an instance of *AVAssetWriterInput* named `input`, and I want to append the data to the input, and then write it to file.

I set *expectsMediaDataInRealTime* to `true` like it said in the docs. When I run the app I get this error:

```
Cannot append sample buffer: Cannot call method when status is 0
```

I use *captureOutput* to get the data from the camera.

```
func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
   // defined on load
   // var input:AVAssetWriterInput

   // Here I get an error
   input.append(sampleBuffer)
}
```

Does the AVAssetWriterInput will handle the encoding of the video? Should I use 2 writers if I want also stream the data?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure call AVAssetWriter.startWriting() before input.append(sampleBuffer)